# Self axis in xslt

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

```
<element>
  <bye>do not delete me</bye>
  <hello>do not delete me</hello>
  <hello>delete me</hello>
  <hello>delete me</hello>
</element>
```

Applied to the above xml, this deletes all the nodes except the first `hello` child of `/element`:

```
<xsl:template match="hello[not(current() = parent::element/hello[1])]" />
```

Why these ones doesn't work? (assuming the first node is not a text node)

```
<xsl:template match="hello[not(self::hello/position() = 1)]" />
<xsl:template match="hello[not(./position() = 1)]" />
```

Or this one?

```
<xsl:template match="hello[not(self::hello[1])]" />
```

What is the `self` axis selecting? Why isn't this last example equivalent to `not(hello[1])`?

Comment: Your question would be a lot clearer if you could post an example of the XML input and the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you are wrong when you say that:

> This deletes all the nodes except the first `hello` child of `/element`

The truth is that it deletes (if that's the correct word) any  `hello` child of `/element` whose value is not the same as the value of the first one of these. For example, given:

**XML**

```
<element>
    <hello>a</hello>
    <hello>b</hello>
    <hello>c</hello>
    <hello>a</hello>
</element>
```

the template:

```
<xsl:template match="hello[not(current() = parent::element/hello[1])]" />
```

will match the second and the third `hello` nodes - but not the first **or the fourth**.

Now, with regard to your question: in XSLT 1.0, `position()` is not a valid location step - so this:

```
<xsl:template match="hello[not(self::hello/position() = 1)]" />
```

should return an error.

In XSLT 2.0, the pattern `hello[not(self::hello/position() = 1)]` will not match **any** `hello` element - because there is only one node on the self axis, and therefore its position is always 1.

Similarly:

```
<xsl:template match="hello[not(./position() = 1)]" />
```

is invalid in XSLT 1.0.

In XSLT 2.0, `./position()` will always return 1 for the same reason as before: `.` is short for `self::node()` and there is  only one such node.

Finally, this template:

```
<xsl:template match="hello[not(self::hello[1])]" />
```

is looking for a node that doesn't have (the first instance of) itself. Of course, no such node can exist.

Comment: You have some good points here. +1. However, I think you meant "In XSLT 2.0, the pattern `hello[not(self::hello/position() = 1)]` will **not** match any `hello` element", because of the `not()` in the predicate.

Comment: @LarsH Thanks for the catch - fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Using position() on the RHS of the "/" operator is never useful -- and in XSLT 1.0, which is the tag on your question, it's not actually permitted.

In XSLT 2.0, the result of the expression X/position() is a sequence of integers 1..count(X). If the LHS is a singleton, like self::E, then count(X) is one so the result is a single integer 1.